# aggregate count changes when multiple returns

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am sending a cypher query through php.

```
match (n:person)-[:watched]->(m:movie)
where m.Title in $mycollection
return count(distinct n.id);
```

this returns the number of people who have watched movies in my collection.
I actually want to return the list of names, and return n.name works fine.

When I try to return n.name and count(distinct n.id) at the same time, I lose the total count and get the count per row.

```
match (n:person)-[:watched]->(m:movie)
where m.Title in $mycollection
return n.name, count(distinct n.id);
```

does not work. The count column appears as 1 for each row.

As I'm using php, I've also tried:

```
$count = $result->getNodesCount();
```

to no avail. So I'm using php to count the array. But it feels like Cypher should be able to do it, right?

Answer (score 1):

`return n.name, count(distinct n.name)` means "return each distinct `n.name` value and its number of distinct values". The number must always be 1, since a distinct value is, obviously, distinct.

If you are actually looking for the number of times each person had an outgoing relationship to a movie whose title is in `$mycollection`, do this instead (where `count(*)` counts the number of times a given `n.name` was matched):

```
MATCH (n:person)-->(m:movie)
WHERE m.Title in $mycollection
RETURN n.name, count(*);
```

Note that the above query omits the `[watched]` pattern found in your query, since that syntax (with no colon before `watched`) does no filtering at all. It merely assigns the relationship to a variable named `watched`, but that variable is not otherwise used, and is therefore superfluous.

If you had intended to use `watched` as the relationship type, then do this instead:

```
MATCH (n:person)-[:watched]->(m:movie)
WHERE m.Title in $mycollection
RETURN n.name, count(*);
```

This modified query returns the number of times each person watched a movie whose title is in `$mycollection`

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer. count(`*`) also does not return the total count if it's in combination with n.name. count(`*`), count(n), and count(distinct n.id) all return the total count when used all by themselves, but return 1 when I also return a property. Sorry I forgot to write in the colon when I copied - I did have it in there. I just find it very puzzling that when I do a query and just add a property to return with the count I get different results for the count. Is it that the count depends on the closest context?

Comment: You are mistaken that `COUNT(*)` always returns 1 when a property is included in the same `RETURN` or `WITH` clause. It all depends on the exact data you are testing with. You need to study the [documentation on aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/), particularly with respect to grouping keys. Playing around with simple examples should help.